# vue js how to set option value selected

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm using vue js for my application in select option input..I need to set default value should be selected in the drop down and while on change i would like to call two functions ..

I'm new to vue js..

My Code :

```
var listingVue = new Vue({

el: '#mountain',

data:{
        formVariables: { 
            country_id: '',
            mountain_id: '',
            peak_id: ''
        },
        countrylist:[],
        mountainlist:[],

},         

ready: function() {

    var datas = this.formVariables;
    this.getCountry();     

},

methods: {

    getCountry: function()
        {

            this.$http.get(baseurl+'/api/v1/device/getCountry',function(response)
            {
                this.$set('countrylist',response.result);      

                //alert(jQuery('#country_id').val());              
            });
        },
    getMountain: function(country_id)
        {
            var datas = this.formVariables;
            datas.$set('country_id', jQuery('#country_id').val() );
            postparemeters = {country_id:datas.country_id};
            this.$http.post(baseurl+'/api/v1/site/getMountain',postparemeters,function(response)
            {
                if(response.result)
                    this.$set('mountainlist',response.result);
                else
                    this.$set('mountainlist','');
            });
        },
```

});

```
 <select 
                    class="breadcrumb_mountain_property" 
                    id="country_id" 
                    v-model="formVariables.country_id" 
                    v-on="change:getMountain(formVariables.country_id);">
                <option 
                  v-repeat = "country: countrylist" 
                  value="@{{country.id}}" >
                  @{{country.name}}
                </option>
            </select>
```

Comment: Which one you want to select? From `v-repeat country`?

Comment: See some of Vue select info on [Vuejs select doc](http://vuejs.org/guide/forms.html#Select)

Answer (score 18):

With vue 2, the provided answer won't work that well. I had the same problem and the vue documentation isn't that clear concerning `<select>`. The only way I found for `<select>` tags to work properly, was this (when talking of the question):

```
<select v-model="formVariables.country_id">
  <option v-for = "country in countrylist" :value="country.id" >{{country.name}}</option>
</select>
```

I assume, that the @-sign in `@{{...}}` was due to blade, it should not be necessary when not using blade.

Comment: I found using this method, it's not possible to set the "selected" option on load. I modified this to use v-model="formVariables.country", where country is the complete object (eg {text:'United States',value:'US' }), not just the value/id. Otherwise this really helped - the documentation on it is pretty minimal... thank you!

Comment: The documentation states, that the "selected" state will be overwritten by the model. I was able to set the selected option by setting the model before rendering the component. Also, you could try to force your component to update after setting the data using `vm.$forceUpdate()` (where vm is your component, so probably `this.$forceUpdate()`...)

Answer (score 10):

In VueJS 2 you can bind `selected` to the default value you want. For example:

```
 <select 
   class="breadcrumb_mountain_property" 
   id="country_id" 
   v-model="formVariables.country_id" 
   v-on:change="getMountain(formVariables.country_id);">
   <option 
       v-for = "country in countrylist"
       :selected="country.id == 1"
       :value="country.id" >
       {{country.name}}
   </option>
 </select>
```

So, during the iteration of the countryList, the country with the id 1 will be selected because `country.id == 1` will be `true` which means `selected="true"`.

UPDATED:
As [Mikee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/987608/mikee) suggested, instead of `v-on="change:getMountain(formVariables.country_id);"` there is a new way to for binding events. There is also a short form `@change="getMountain(formVariables.country_id);"`

Comment: Won't this mean that all items are selected because if the `selected` attribute exists, it will be selected, as the attribute doesn't require a value, just it's presence.

Comment: thanks, @Mikee that is true, let me update the answer to show the new way to do this.

Answer (score 3):

You should use the '`options`' attribute in place of trying to v-repeat `<option></option>`:

**VM**

```
data: {    
  countryList: [
    { text:'United States',value:'US' },
    { text:'Canada',value:'CA' }
  ]
},

watch: {
  'formVariables.country_id': function() {
    // do any number of things on 'change'
   }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<select 
  class="breadcrumb_mountain_property" 
  id="country_id" 
  v-model="formVariables.country_id" 
  options="countryList">
</select>
```

Comment: Why should we use options instead of v-for? I find value in using v-for because it lets me bind :value and :label separately when iterating through objects.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this way.

```
<select v-model="userData.categoryId" class="input mb-3">
      <option disabled value="null">Kategori</option>
      <option
        v-for="category in categoryList"
        :key="category.id"
        :value="category.id"
      >
        {{ category.name }}
      </option>
</select>

export default {
  data() {
    return {
     categoryList: [],
      userData: {
        title: null,       
        categoryId: null,
      },
    };
  },
```

The important thing here is what the categoryId value is, the default option value should be that.

```
categoryId: null,
<option disabled value="null">Kategori</option>
```

Here we use categoryId as value in v-model and initialize it with null. Value must be null in default option.

```
<select v-model="userData.categoryId" class="input mb-3">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use select in this way. Remember to use array in v-for.

```
  <select v-model="album.primary_artist">
        <option v-for="i in artistList" :key="i.id" :value="i.name">
          {{ i.name }}
        </option>
  </select>
```